# What is the dijitReset class for?

Tags: javascript, css, dojo

I have seen the class `dijitReset` on many different HTML elements in examples and samples, but I cannot find an explanation for what this class is intended for. Here is an example (with no explanation) in the `dijit.form` documentation:

```
<span class="dijit dijitReset dijitLeft dijitInline"
  data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:_onButtonClick,onmouseenter:_onMouse,onmouseleave:_onMouse,onmousedown:_onMouse"
  ><span class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitInline"
      ><span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode"
          ><button class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents"
              data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode,focusNode"
              name="${name}" type="${type}" value="${value}" role="button" aria-labelledby="${id}_label"
              ><span class="dijitReset dijitInline" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode"
                  ><span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">&#10003;</span
              ></span
              ><span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText"
                  id="${id}_label"
                  data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode"
              ></span
          ></button
      ></span
  ></span
></span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Dojo source code file `dijit.css`:

```
.dijitReset 
{ 
/* Use this style to null out padding, margin, border in your   
      template elements so that page specific styles don't break them. 
- Use in all TABLE, TR and TD tags. 
*/ 

margin:0; 
border:0; 
padding:0; 
line-height:normal; 
font: inherit; 
color: inherit; 
}
```

So it is intended to reset page-specific styles for margin, border, and padding so they do not break your Dojo template objects.